# Learning Basic JSON, MySQL and its connection

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

im currently developing an android application, previously I worked with offline SQLite database for android, and now I'm trying to learn about online database, (currently still working with XAMPP localhost)

I have read some tutorials but still kinda confused about JSon, MySQL, and its connection..

I want to ask several basic concepts here, to clarify what I got and to prevent myself not to lost my way further,

(Correct me if i'm wrong) So in short when I want to make my application stored database online and do CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) operation, this is what should be done :

1. Make a connection between my .php file and my database
2. Connect my android device with my php file
3. Passed data from java to php using JSON
4. PHP will get data with $_POST or $_GET then stored it in local variable
5. PHP will do query using passed variable from java
6. PHP will return something using JSON_encode
7. Java will get them with JSON as well

Then I watched and see this tutorial - [MyBringBack Tutorial](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13193/android-mysql-php-json-part-5-developing-the-android-application/..)

And tried to implements what's there.. I tried to run those codes in my pc-browser and it worked,  But when I tried to run those codes in my android device, it doesn't work, it doesn't return anything, and I don't know where is my wrong,

Could you please help me to check these codes?

Thank you in advance

Here are my code :

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText etUsername;
private EditText etPassword;
private Button bLogin, bRegis, bAdmin;
userSessionManager session;
Database checkLogin = new Database(LoginActivity.this);
static final String loginUrl = "http://192.168.0.102:8081/webservice/doLogin.php";

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "Success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "Message";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String a,b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
    session = new userSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    Declaration();
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    bRegis.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAdmin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void Declaration() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLoginUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLoginPassword);
    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bLogin:
        new AttemptLogin().execute();

        break;
}



class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), username+password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            //Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(loginUrl, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.USERVIEW");
                startActivity(intent);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "a",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.ROOTVIEW");
                startActivity(intent);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

}

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}


// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

doLogin.php

```
<?php 

require("config.inc.php");

if(!empty($_POST)){
//gets user's info based off a username

    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please enter both username n password";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $query = "SELECT MemberUsername, MemberPassword From Member Where MemberUsername = :username";

    $query_params = array(':username' => $_POST['username']);

    try{
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        $response["succeess"] =0;
        $response["message"]= "Database error1. please try again"; 
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $validate_info=false;

    //fetching rows from query
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $login_ok=false;

    if($row){
        if($_POST['password']==$row['MemberPassword']){
        $login_ok=true;
        }
    }

    if($login_ok){
    //userLogin
        $response["success"]=1;
        $reponse["message"] = "Login Successfull";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }else{
        $response["success"]=0;
        $response["message"]= "Login Failed";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

}

else {
?>

<h1> Register </h1>
<form action = "doLogin.php" method="post"> 
    Username : <br />
    <input type = "text" name = "username" placeholder= "user name"> <br/>
    Password : <br />
    <input type = "password" name = "password" placeholder= "password"> <br/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "login" >
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `it doesn't work, and I don't know where is my wrong`?

Comment: Doesn't work doesn't tell us much. HOW did it not work? You got errors? crashes? Corrupted data? No data?

Comment: It doen't return anything, I created intent inside doInBackground and Check the result that is passed from php to java..

Comment: there could be other issues, but for sure, in Java you can't compare String using `==`, like `if(method == "POST")` you should replace it with `if(method.equals("POST"))`

Comment: @Yazan thank you, found my problem, it is because the string, thank you!

Comment: @JuliusLeo, good to hear that, i have posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there could be other issues, but for sure, in Java you can't compare String using `==`, like `if(method == "POST")` you should replace it with `if(method.equals("POST"))` and same for all other `==` for String compare

once `makeHttpRequest()` is invoked, nothing matches with method if statement, 
and no http calls are made, so the method will return Null.